# Azure DevOps Archive Work Items (Test Cases)

Tags: azure-devops, integration-testing, testcase

I've done some searching but can't find an answer to this.  In our current Test Case Management System, we have an option to archive Test Cases which are no longer relevant (eg because an API or UI option was removed).  The TC still exists, but just cannot be executed in any Test Suites any longer.

However, I cannot find any such option in Azure DevOps ... is there ?  The closest I can find is deleting a work item, but that's obviously not what I'm after.  I know that other work items (stories, epics, bugs etc) have a defined beginning and end, but TCs tend to stay around as long as they are relevant (for automation/regression testing etc), so I feel they should have a slightly different lifecycle than other work items.

Anybody found a way of doing this in Azure DevOps or found an alternate solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out-of-box features for that. You may try on of these suggestions:

1. Just add new tag "Deprecated" or "Archive". [Add work item tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/add-tags-to-work-items?view=azure-devops)
2. Add area path "Archive" and move work items to it. [Define area paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)
3. Edit your process template and add new state "Archive" to "Remove" category in the test case work item type. [Add a workflow state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops#add-a-workflow-state)